# How to increase speed of rendering page from .jsp (in use: Spring Webflow)

Tags: java, spring, performance, servlet-filters

I did profiling of my application and I founded bottleneck. ~15% of whole processing time is take to rendering .jsp page.

This is a part of report from jprofiler (4.0)

```
    /WEB-INF/jsp/summary.jsp [org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jsp.summary_jsp]    291 s (14 %)   342 ms  851
  14,7% - 291 s - 851 hot spot inv. org.springframework.webflow.mvc.servlet.FlowController.handleRequest
  14,7% - 291 s - 851 hot spot inv. pl.myexcelion.checkout.web.controller.FlowController.handleRequest
  14,7% - 291 s - 851 hot spot inv. org.aspectj.lang.ProceedingJoinPoint.proceed
  14,7% - 291 s - 851 hot spot inv. pl.myexcelion.checkout.main.aspect.DebugLevelLoggerAspect.logMethodComplex
  14,7% - 291 s - 851 hot spot inv. javax.servlet.FilterChain.doFilter
  14,7% - 291 s - 851 hot spot inv. pl.myexcelion.checkout.web.security.filter.RestDispatcherFilter.doFilterInternal
  14,7% - 291 s - 851 hot spot inv. javax.servlet.FilterChain.doFilter
  14,7% - 291 s - 851 hot spot inv. pl.myexcelion.checkout.web.security.filter.ChangeLanguageFilter.doFilterInternal
  14,7% - 291 s - 851 hot spot inv. javax.servlet.FilterChain.doFilter
  14,7% - 291 s - 851 hot spot inv. pl.myexcelion.checkout.web.security.filter.ProtectedResourcesFilter.doFilterInternal
  14,7% - 291 s - 851 hot spot inv. javax.servlet.FilterChain.doFilter
  14,7% - 291 s - 851 hot spot inv. pl.myexcelion.checkout.web.security.filter.SaveLanguageAfterLoginFilter.doFilterInternal
  14,7% - 291 s - 851 hot spot inv. javax.servlet.FilterChain.doFilter
  14,7% - 291 s - 851 hot spot inv. pl.myexcelion.checkout.web.security.filter.RequestApplicationContextFilter.doFilterInternal
  14,7% - 291 s - 851 hot spot inv. javax.servlet.FilterChain.doFilter
  14,7% - 291 s - 851 hot spot inv. com.myexcelion.commons.web.filter.MobileAppFilter.doMobileFilter
  14,7% - 291 s - 851 hot spot inv. com.myexcelion.commons.web.filter.MobileAppFilter.doFilter
  14,7% - 291 s - 851 hot spot inv. javax.servlet.FilterChain.doFilter
  14,7% - 291 s - 851 hot spot inv. com.myexcelion.commons.web.filters.F5Filter.doFilter
  14,7% - 291 s - 851 hot spot inv. com.myexcelion.commons.web.filters.F5Filter.doFilter
  14,7% - 291 s - 851 hot spot inv. javax.servlet.FilterChain.doFilter
  14,7% - 291 s - 851 hot spot inv. com.myexcelion.commons.web.filter.CookieAwareFilter.doFilter
  14,7% - 291 s - 851 hot spot inv. URL: /checkout-web/summary
  14,7% - 291 s - 851 hot spot inv. org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run
```

As you can see I got handle request used `org.springframework.webflow.mvc.servlet.FlowController.handleRequest` and after that I run filters in chain.

Do you have any idea how to speed up the processing of these filters and whole piece of the application?

Comment: How is 15% a bottleneck?

Comment: This is a really long process through 5 components and this rendering takes 15% of whole time of processing.

Comment: Isn't it the other way around? The controller is (normally) called after all the filters have processed else it would be strange. To decrease your time, decrease the amount of work that is done in your JSP. How to optimze is hard to see/tell without seeing the actual code.